# Expect Procedure for SSH Login

Tags: tcl, expect

I'm new to Expect scripting.  I'm trying to create a procedure that will connect to routers/switches over SSH and fall back to telnet if that fails.  The code that I have works fine before I put it inside a procedure.  I'm sure there's something I'm not understanding about how procedures work.  When I call it as a procedure it does connect via SSH which receives "Connection refused" and falls back to telnet like it is supposed to, it just never logs in with the password.  When I enable debug mode I see it sends the password but for some reason the router doesn't seem like it receives it.  It just sits at the Password: prompt until it times out.

```
proc connectToTerminal { username hostname password } {
    # Run ssh, don't display key warning
    spawn ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no $username\@$hostname

    # Allow this script to handle ssh connection issues, fall back to telnet
    expect {
        timeout { send_user "\nTimeout Exceeded - Check Host\n"; exit 1 }
        eof { send_user "\nSSH Connection To $hostname Failed\n"; exit 1 }
        # If we have the correct prompt, continue
        "*#" {}
        # If it's asking for the password, it can have it
        "*assword:" { send "$password\n" }
        # Fall back to telnet if connection refused
        "Connection refused" { 
            spawn telnet $hostname
            #expect "username:" 
            #send "$username\n"
            expect "*assword:" 
            send "$password\n"
        }
        # Fall back to telnet if connection is closed by [ip address]
        -re {closed by \d{1,3}.\d{1,3}.\d{1,3}.\d{1,3}} { 
            spawn telnet $hostname
            #expect "username:" 
            #send "$username\n"
            expect "*assword:"
            send "$password\n" 
        }
        # Use SSH v1 if the device is only accepting v1 
        "2 vs. 1" { 
            spawn ssh -1 -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no $username\@$hostname
            expect {
                "*assword:" { send "$password\n" }
                timeout { 
                    spawn telnet $hostname
                    #expect "username:" 
                    #send "$username\n"
                    expect "*assword:"
                    send "$password\n"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

connectToTerminal $username $hostname $password
```

Below is the debug output when I run the script

```
spawn ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no wmh@172.16.1.195
parent: waiting for sync byte
parent: telling child to go ahead
parent: now unsynchronized from child
spawn: returns {7726}
Gate keeper glob pattern for 'closed by \d{1,3}.\d{1,3}.\d{1,3}.\d{1,3}' is 'closed by *'. Activating booster.

expect: does "" (spawn_id exp6) match glob pattern "*#"? no
"*assword:"? no
"Connection refused"? no
"closed by \d{1,3}.\d{1,3}.\d{1,3}.\d{1,3}"? Gate "closed by *"? gate=no
"2 vs. 1"? no
ssh: connect to host 172.16.1.195 port 22: Connection refused

expect: does "ssh: connect to host 172.16.1.195 port 22: Connection refused\r\r\n" (spawn_id exp6) match glob pattern "*#"? no
"*assword:"? no
"Connection refused"? yes
expect: set expect_out(0,string) "Connection refused"
expect: set expect_out(spawn_id) "exp6"
expect: set expect_out(buffer) "ssh: connect to host 172.16.1.195 port 22: Connection refused"
spawn telnet 172.16.1.195
parent: waiting for sync byte
parent: telling child to go ahead
parent: now unsynchronized from child
spawn: returns {7730}

expect: does "" (spawn_id exp7) match glob pattern "*assword:"? no
Trying 172.16.1.195...

expect: does "Trying 172.16.1.195...\r\n" (spawn_id exp7) match glob pattern "*assword:"? no
Connected to 172.16.1.195.
expect: does "Trying 172.16.1.195...\r\nConnected to 172.16.1.195." (spawn_id exp7) match glob pattern "*assword:"? no


expect: does "Trying 172.16.1.195...\r\nConnected to 172.16.1.195.\r\n" (spawn_id exp7) match glob pattern "*assword:"? no
Escape character is '^]'.
expect: does "Trying 172.16.1.195...\r\nConnected to 172.16.1.195.\r\nEscape character is '^]'." (spawn_id exp7) match glob pattern "*assword:"? no


expect: does "Trying 172.16.1.195...\r\nConnected to 172.16.1.195.\r\nEscape character is '^]'.\r\n" (spawn_id exp7) match glob pattern "*assword:"? no
C
*********************************************************************
*                                                                   *
*                                                                   *
*                                                                   *
*              THIS COMPUTER IS FOR PRIVATE USE ONLY                *
*              -------------------------------------                *
*                                                                   *
*    UNAUTHORIZED access to and/or use of this computer syst
expect: does "Trying 172.16.1.195...\r\nConnected to 172.16.1.195.\r\nEscape character is '^]'.\r\nC\r\n*********************************************************************\r\n*                                                                   *\r\n*                                                                   *\r\n*                                                                   *\r\n*              THIS COMPUTER IS FOR PRIVATE USE ONLY                *\r\n*              -------------------------------------                *\r\n*                                                                   *\r\n*    UNAUTHORIZED access to and/or use of this computer syst" (spawn_id exp7) match glob pattern "*assword:"? no
em      *
*    is a violation of law and is punishable under provisions of    *
*    19 USC 1029 and 18 USC 1030, and applicable statutes. Use      *
*    of this system constitutes consent to security testing and     *
*    monitoring.                                                    *
*                                                                   *
*                               11-12-13                            *
*********************************************************************


User Access Verification

Password: 
expect: does "Trying 172.16.1.195...\r\nConnected to 172.16.1.195.\r\nEscape character is '^]'.\r\nC\r\n*********************************************************************\r\n*                                                                   *\r\n*                                                                   *\r\n*                                                                   *\r\n*              THIS COMPUTER IS FOR PRIVATE USE ONLY                *\r\n*              -------------------------------------                *\r\n*                                                                   *\r\n*    UNAUTHORIZED access to and/or use of this computer system      *\r\n*    is a violation of law and is punishable under provisions of    *\r\n*    19 USC 1029 and 18 USC 1030, and applicable statutes. Use      *\r\n*    of this system constitutes consent to security testing and     *\r\n*    monitoring.                                                    *\r\n*                                                                   *\r\n*                               11-12-13                            *\r\n*********************************************************************\r\n\r\n\r\nUser Access Verification\r\n\r\nPassword: " (spawn_id exp7) match glob pattern "*assword:"? yes
expect: set expect_out(0,string) "Trying 172.16.1.195...\r\nConnected to 172.16.1.195.\r\nEscape character is '^]'.\r\nC\r\n*********************************************************************\r\n*                                                                   *\r\n*                                                                   *\r\n*                                                                   *\r\n*              THIS COMPUTER IS FOR PRIVATE USE ONLY                *\r\n*              -------------------------------------                *\r\n*                                                                   *\r\n*    UNAUTHORIZED access to and/or use of this computer system      *\r\n*    is a violation of law and is punishable under provisions of    *\r\n*    19 USC 1029 and 18 USC 1030, and applicable statutes. Use      *\r\n*    of this system constitutes consent to security testing and     *\r\n*    monitoring.                                                    *\r\n*                                                                   *\r\n*                               11-12-13                            *\r\n*********************************************************************\r\n\r\n\r\nUser Access Verification\r\n\r\nPassword:"
expect: set expect_out(spawn_id) "exp7"
expect: set expect_out(buffer) "Trying 172.16.1.195...\r\nConnected to 172.16.1.195.\r\nEscape character is '^]'.\r\nC\r\n*********************************************************************\r\n*                                                                   *\r\n*                                                                   *\r\n*                                                                   *\r\n*              THIS COMPUTER IS FOR PRIVATE USE ONLY                *\r\n*              -------------------------------------                *\r\n*                                                                   *\r\n*    UNAUTHORIZED access to and/or use of this computer system      *\r\n*    is a violation of law and is punishable under provisions of    *\r\n*    19 USC 1029 and 18 USC 1030, and applicable statutes. Use      *\r\n*    of this system constitutes consent to security testing and     *\r\n*    monitoring.                                                    *\r\n*                                                                   *\r\n*                               11-12-13                            *\r\n*********************************************************************\r\n\r\n\r\nUser Access Verification\r\n\r\nPassword:"
send: sending "cisco\n" to { exp7 }

expect: does "" (spawn_id exp0) match glob pattern "*#"? no
"*>"? no
expect: timed out
```

Comment: I was using Expect a few days ago and remember seeing the manual page saying that when you want to `send` the equivalent of pressing return, that you should use `\r` rather than `\n`. Maybe that fixes things?

Comment: Gave that a shot but it did not make a difference.  Thanks for the suggestion though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After sending the password, just add one more `expect` statement.

```
set prompt "#"
send "$password \r"
expect "$prompt"
```

Unless we explicitly tell `Expect` to wait for it, it won't expect anything from the session.

**Update :**

I'm not sure if you have missed the `expect` statement or misplaced it in the caller procedure.   Update your issues if still not solved.

If you have placed the `expect` statement in another proc, then the `spawn_id` should be passed on to it, so that `Expect` can wait for it properly. Else, the default behavior will be restored if `spawn_id` is empty. i.e. it will expect from the `stdin`.

It is evident from your debug output

```
expect: does "" (spawn_id exp0) match glob pattern "*#"? no
```

where `exp0` is nothing but the `stdin`. Inside that procedure, after spawning the `telnet` , you can save the `spawn_id` in to another variable and return it to caller procedure where it can be used.

Comment: This cannot explain why the code worked fine before it was put in a procedure. I guess the OP only pasted part of the script.

Comment: @whjm : I hope I addressed it now.

Comment: If there's only one program to be `spawn`ed then we can just add `global spawn_id` at the beginning of the `proc` to make it a global var.